# Why SQL Exception?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on this asp.net webservice using MVC5, C# to manage products, on Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

When I added the database connection, and ran it from index.cshtml to see the products/index page, but Visual Studio gave me this error.

> SQL Exception was unhandled by user code. An exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

I'm a beginner so I researched as much as I could, and I don't see my error, how can I fix it?

EDIT: Could the error be that I don't have phpMyAdmin installed for MySQL?

II EDIT: I just realized that this new machine doesnt have my old configuration, I will install MySQL and report back. Thanks.

Thanks!

This is my Product class (model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCStart.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastBuy { get; set; }
        public float Stock { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
using MVCStart.Context;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCStart.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private StoreContext db = new StoreContext();

        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Products.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Product/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Product/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Product/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Product/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Product/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my StoreContext for database:

```
using MVCStart.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCStart.Context
{
    public class StoreContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my view with html:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCStart.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastBuy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stock)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastBuy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

This is my webconfig with database settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoreContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Market;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a SQL server running on your local machine and is it turned on? It is trying to connect to it and timing out. Data Source=. means localhost. If you are trying to connect to MySQL you will need to change the connection string in your web.config

Comment: No, I just realized that I just moved to a new machine and this one doesnt have my old configuration, sorry. I will install it and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Your Web.Config is configured for Sql Server, not MySql.  You can also see this by reading the exception your getting : 
`Could not open a connection to SQL Server`

Comment: Search for the error message in StackOverflow, Bing or Google first. You will find a ton of answers for this situation.

Comment: @KiNeTiC Thanks! Yes, it seems that is the problem. I installed MySQL connector for Visual Studio and mysql connection shows as successful, but when I check the webconfig, it still shows the connection for SQL Server. How can I solve this?

Comment: @4201 You will need to change the connection string yourself. The MySQL connector is just a library to help you connect. Try Googling for MySQL web.config connection strings and you should be able to get it :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Server Explorer from VS via View->Server Explorer.
Open Data Connections and Delete related connection (StoreContext ) .
Then Add a new connection via right click Data Connnections .